# How is cohesion different from adhesion?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand *cohesion,* but it looks similar to *adhesion*.

I want to know how *cohesion* is different from *adhesion*
Could you please give an example (basic English)?

I am trying to understand this from the computer science perspective.

Comment: @snailboat I have added context.. and thank you very much

Comment: @PeterParker I'm not sure about "adhesion" in the context of coding. (I've never heard of it in this context.) You can find more information about cohesion on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29. Personally, I prefer saying "tight/loose coupling", which is basically the same idea.

Comment: @snailboat: Do you know any "technical context" meaning for ***adhesion*** in respect of computer science? I don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nope, just *cohesion*.  [I asked the same question on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22830647#22830647), but so far no one knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Cohesion*** generally refers to the ability/tendency of a homogeneous substance or mixture of different things/ingredients to...

> [**cohere**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohere) *- to hold together firmly **as parts of the same mass***
>    (alternate) *- to be logically or aesthetically **consistent***

***Adhesion*** generally relates to the ability of something to...

> [**adhere**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adhere) *- to stick **to something** : to attach firmly to something*
>    (alternate) - *to hold fast or stick by or as if **by gluing**, suction, grasping, or fusing*

(Italics mine, to emphasize those aspects that normally distinguish the two words.)

Thus one could say that something exhibits *cohesion* all on its own (it stays together in a lump), but *adhesion* normally implies *sticking **to** something else*.

---

In the context of software, [***cohesion***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) *refers to the degree to which the elements of a module belong together*. I'm not aware of any domain-specific sense of ***adhesion*** in the context of computing.

Comment: *Cohere* means to "stick together", *adhere" means to "stick on the outside of."

Answer (score 3):

Cohesion has a specific meaning in Computer Science that relates to the similarity of elements within a larger system. While it is most commonly used in software engineering to describe how closely the methods of a class are related to the purpose of the class, it can also used in broader terms - you could say that the StackExchange family of communities are a quite cohesive system.

I've not heard of adhesion being used in relation to CS although adhere as a verb is used - we adhere (or, at least, we should try to) to standards.

So, you could say that "we adhere to best practice in OOP by ensuring that we write classes with with a high degree of cohesion."

I guess that you could mangle that sentence to use both adhesion and cohesion and still have it make sense, but it would sound awkward.

Answer (score 0):

In my notes from my 2016 programming practices class, there's 
 Coupling: The degree of reliance on other modules/functions.
Cohesion: The degree to which a function adheres to one task.

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thank you for answering. We're building a database of questions and answers about English usage, so it's important to really answer the question, which asks _how cohesion is different from adhesion._ We hope you'll ask questions of your own, too!